# Compiler error LNK2019 when compiling Google Breakpad on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, google-breakpad

So I'm trying to integrate Google Breakpad into my application following this tutorial: http://zxstudio.org/blog/2014/10/28/integrating-google-breakpad/

I've come to the point where when I compile, I get the LNK2019 compiler error. After some research, I found out that it has to do with the `Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type` compiler option.(http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38581-linking-google-breakpad-lib-in-our-Qt-app-on-Windows-gives-Unresolved-external-symbol). I've tried to enable/disable this option, but no luck.

Any suggestions?:)

Comment: I have the same problem, and found this (not solved?)

https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/issues/detail?id=536

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type" to no (since you seem to be using pre-built Qt with that option) on your project and, more importantly, on breakpad project. (the lib that provides the symbol you are missing).

This option must match on all static libraries and dlls exporting C++ symbols. (if they use wchar_t at all)